# How to access events of a properties.settings.default field in C#?

Tags: c#, properties, screensaver, multithreading, properties.settings

I have two forms, Form A and Form B. My Properties.Settings.Default has a timer object that when "ticked" needs to open Form B. What I would like to do is program the timer_tick(object sender, Eventargs e) event for the timer object that is in the solution's properties. 
Is this possible? If so how?

The issue I am having is I don't know the syntax to program events for properties.

Any help/alternate ways would be much appreciated.

P.S. What I am essentially trying to do is trigger a screen saver (Form B) after x seconds but when Form B is clicked it needs to re-enable the timer and close itself.

Comment: Why do you hold the timer object in the settings?

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer object property on Form B.  When the timer goes off and you are opening Form B, assign the timer property on the new Form B your timer object.  When Form B is clicked, set the the timer property to start again and close your form.